# Always shows test mode on payment page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, razorpay

Hello I have replaced the test api key of razorpay to live key in my laravel project but when i go to the payment page it still shows the test mode.

I have updated razor key in .env and backend admin panel the key is saved to the database also.

Comment: Please show how you're accessing the env variable. Perhaps it is cached.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your project cache, if you didn't try that already:

```
composer dump-autload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```